# How to Add Bootstrap 4 Tooltips in Shiny App

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, shiny

The following code can be used to show how I would want a tooltip to appear. If `version=3` then the function in shinyBS works and produces the tooltip. However with `version=4` it does not work. I don't want to use the shinyBS package as it seems it's still in dev mode and would rather just straight prefer to wrap my button with some HTML using tooltips from bootstrap directly as shown [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/).

I'm not having success in doing it this way and wonder if anyone can suggest a good way to get the tool top for my button just using the pure HTML?

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(

    navbarPage(
        theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly", version = 4),
        title = 'Methods',
        tabPanel('One'),
    ),
    mainPanel(
        h1('Hello World'),      
        actionButton("button", "Some Button"),
        bsTooltip("button", "Something to be said here", "top"),
        
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Not pure HTML but you could use the [prompter](https://github.com/etiennebacher/prompter) package. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of this package)

Comment: {bsplus} is another good alternative